# batch file to make changes in uppercase only in variable

Tags: batch-file, uppercase

i want batch file to make changes in uppercase only not in the lowercase

the changes is to make before every A (etc from alphabetical) to -A

lets say he wrote "AbkijCljfs" after comparison it will be "-Abkij-Cljfs"

without external file using cmd only

Comment: This can be done in a 4/5 lines of VBScript/.vbs which would probably be an easier way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "string=AbkijCljfs"

    set "buffer="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        cmd /q /u /c "(echo(%string%)" ^| more 
    ') do (
        set "dash=-"
        for /f "delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%b in ("%%a") do set "dash="
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!buffer!!dash!") do (
            endlocal
            set "buffer=%%b%%a"
        )
    )
    echo([%buffer%]
```

This uses an unicode `cmd` instance piped into `more` to split the string and a `for` loop to determine if each of the characters is or not uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed or perl

`echo 'AbC' | sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\1/g'`

Do that for each file

```
for i in `ls -1`; do
    sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/-\1/g' $i > $i_fixed
done
```

Or you can use `ed` to do it in place

Comment: oh i forget to write "without external file using cmd only"

Comment: What does "without external file using cmd only" mean?

Comment: Using only commands native to Windows batch environment. Some companies do not allow download of 3rd party utilities.

Comment: Oh, it didn't saw pure win in there, so I assumed you had access to basic Unix/Linux/Mac command shell. Glad the other person was able to answer